# When does handle_read and handle_write are called?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am starting to work with asio boost, and now I am coding a async server.
But I don't understand when does handle_read or handle_write are called,
where can I code what will happen when a message is sent and received?
Need to write a function that is called when a request is sent to me and then to send a reply but don't get which functions are they.

```cpp
void tcp_connection::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
    size_t bytes_transferred)
{
}

void tcp_connection::handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error,
    size_t bytes_transferred)
{
}
```

I expect the names of the functions that are called when a data is sent to socket and send. and how to use.